# server side display string width

Tags: c#

How can I calculate the display width size of a string based on a font family (arial) and size in pixels (12px)? (if necessary, assume zoom level 100%)

I have seem a few posts about it, but I still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the TextRenderer class - see MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ye7hc8.aspx

Here is an example Console application that measures the string "This is some text":

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TextMeasureExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TextRenderer.MeasureText("This is some text", new Font("Arial", 0.75f)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the 12 it's not in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

That can be tough to do accurately.  But this should point you in the right direction: [how to use System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1439998.aspx/1)